# How to generate an APK for Android 4.1.2 with ionic cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, build, apk

I just got into android programming with ionic and cordova. I installed the latest versions of ionic and cordova. the problem is when I build, the apk does not install on my android 4.1.2
What can I do

Answer (score 0):

Config.xml

change line

```
 <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
```

To

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
```

Hope it will help you out.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I try to do it but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I received this message :

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseManifest'.

  > Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:CordovaLib] C:\Users\Azman\Projets\test5\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build\intermediates\library_manifest\release\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
  >       Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
  >               or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
  >               or use tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.